# Pokemon Omega Ruby Bundle Transfer

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire, nintendo-network-id

Recently, I've had problems with my NNID account and wish to make a new one on the same console. My question is, If I restart my NNID account, will my Omega Ruby download be safe, or will it also be deleted, even with the SD card removed?

Comment: I'd suggest contacting Nintendo Support first to see if you can recover the NNID account you had 'problems' with, or if they could transfer your 'purchaces' to a new account. Because your Nintendo Store downloads are tied to your NNID. Even if you managed to preserve the game on your SD card, you may be screwed in the future if you ever needed to re-download (Plus, not sure if patches would be affected).

Comment: If you change your NNID you won't be able to access any downloaded content tied to the previous NNID account.

Answer (score 1):

You can make sure that your downloaded game is located on your SD card. When you reset your NNID account it shouldn't affect your SD card. To be safe you can remove your SD card before you reset your NNID

Comment: But is my ORAS account set on that DS even if it is located on the SD? Like if I used that SD on another DS, would it have all my Data?

Comment: Data is saved locally in the SD gamefile/Cartridge

Comment: You two are LEGENDS!

Comment: I do recommend trying to do as @Trent commented. The purchase is indeed tied to your account altho the saved might not. It might cause a conflict if you have to redownload it on a new device

Comment: I didn't purchase ORAS from the Eshop, but it came in with a Red see-through 2DS, and the game was pre-installed

Comment: Hmm Than the game is probably not bound to your Account. Still i'd send a support ticket to nintendo to verify because im not 100% sure about that